# Python algorithm for lists and sublists

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a number of lists that can be "opened" or "closed", something like this:

```
lista = ["a", "b", "c"]
listb = ["d", "e"]
listc = ["a", "b", "e"]
listd = ["c", "d"]
```

I have a master list of all open items:

```
all_open = ["a", "b", "c", "e"]
```

and a list of open lists:

```
open_lists = ["lista", "listc"]
```

As the sublists are openend, their items are added to the master list:

```
open_lists.append("listb")
for each i in listb:
    if !(i in all_open):
        all_open.append(i)
```

Is there a simple algorithm to remove items from the master list when a sublist is closed? The goal is to not remove items that belong to other lists that are still open.

Comment: What does it **mean** for a list, or an item, to be "open"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep track of how many lists each item was from.  The simplest way to do that is with a map.  I like to use `collections.Counter` for something like this.

```
import collections
count = collections.Counter()

# add a list
for i in listb:
    if count[i] == 0:
        all_open.append(i)
    count[i] += 1

# delete a list
for i in listb:
    count[i] -= 1
    if count[i] == 0:
        all_open.remove(i)
```

In addition, you can get rid of `all_open` altogether and use the `count.keys()` iterator instead.

Comment: (Note that this is basically what's usually referred to as "reference counting", and is often used in garbage collection algorithms.)

Comment: Reference counting is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
all_items = []
for l in open_lists:
    for item in l:
       if item not in all_items:
           all_items.append(item)

all_open = [item for item in all_open if item not in all_items]
```

I believe this will results in what you desire although I'm not too clear if that's what you are asking for. You could also keep track of how many times each item is open, and when you close a list, decrease that by 1. If the value is 0, then remove an item. Might be a lot more efficient than this.